# Error while starting fabric network 1.4 : ailed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm setting up new fabric network and am encountering this error:

```
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup orderer.example.com on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host"
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

My commands:

```
./scripts/bootstrap.sh 1.4.1 1.4.1 0.4.14
cd first-network
./byfn.sh generate
sudo ./byfn.sh up
```

I expect fabric network to start.

I ran `docker ps -a`, and it shows that container orderer exited (2) about an hour ago.

Answer (score 0):

So your orderer container is exited. There are times when some already created docker volumes sometimes messed up with your new network setup. So to avoid these things you can stop your network and clean your docker volumes using:

```
docker volume prune
```

Then again restart your network. See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks , but doesn't help

Comment: first Bring down network using ./byfn.sh down then bring it up ./byfn.sh up

Comment: same issue here. did you solve this problem? I have tried bringing down all the images and restarting, also tried hosts entry. nothing work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this happens, but stopping the containers and removing the images can solve the problem. You can try one of the below methods:

**Method 1:**

To stop the containers by `sudo docker stop $(sudo docker
   ps -aq)` and then remove them by running `sudo docker rm $(sudo
   docker ps -aq)`. Now start your network again with `./network.sh up`

**Method 2:**

1. Export path variables from the latest bin folder inside the fabric-sample folder just downloaded:  `export PATH=~/workspace/fabric-samples/bin:$PATH`
2. Make the files in the bin folder executable by using chmod. For me, the `chmod -x` didn't work. So I have been extra generous and provided with `chmod 777` permissions:

`chmod 777 ~/workspace/fabric-samples/bin/configtxgen`
`chmod 777 ~/workspace/fabric-samples/bin/configtxlator`
`chmod 777 ~/workspace/fabric-samples/bin/cryptogen`
`chmod 777 ~/workspace/fabric-samples/bin/discover`
`chmod 777 ~/workspace/fabric-samples/bin/fabric-ca-client`
`chmod 777 ~/workspace/fabric-samples/bin//idemixgen`
`chmod 777 ~/workspace/fabric-samples/bin/orderer`
`chmod 777 ~/workspace/fabric-samples/bin/peer`
`chmod 777 ~/workspace/property-registration/network/crypto-config.yaml`

`chmod 777 ~/workspace/property-registration/network/fabricNetwork.sh`
`chmod 777 ~/workspace/property-registration/network/docker-compose.yml`
`chmod 777 ~/workspace/property-registration/network/configtx.yaml`
`chmod 777 ~/workspace/property-registration/network/docker-compose-e2e.yml`
`chmod 777 ~/workspace/property-registration/network/docker-compose-template.yaml`
`chmod 777 ~/workspace/property-registration/network/scripts/bootstrap.sh`

3. Generate certs and channel-artifacts: `./network.sh generate`
4. Make the genesis.block executable by using chmod: `chmod 667 /channel-artifacts/genesis.block`
5. Make sure the private keys in the docker-compose-e2e.yml file are updated with the latest CA keys. Open the docker-compose-e2e.yml file and inspect function replacePrivateKey.
6. Start the docker container using the compose file `docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml up -d` Check if all the containers are running using `docker ps -a`
7. Run the bootstrap script and connect the peers with each other: `./network.sh retry`

Method 2 worked out for me. It seems like one of the files did not have the right executable permissions. You may have to do this again the next time you restart your laptop - or make a script file to automate it.